# ThreeJS - adding objects in different order affects alpha / display

Tags: javascript, three.js

My program creates dynamic number of point cloud objects with custom attributes that includes the alpha value of each particle. This works fine, however, when the objects are nested within each other (say spheres) the smaller (inner) ones are getting obscured by the bigger ones, even though their particles' alpha is set properly. When I reverse the order of adding the point-cloud objects to the scene, starting with the bigger ones, going down to the smaller ones, I can see the smaller ones thru the bigger ones.
My question is whether there is a way to tell the renderer to update or recalculate the alpha values or re-render the smaller inner objects so that they show up?

Comment: Can you add a small code example that will reproduce your problem?

Comment: I guess this is a fragment-shader problem.. not sure, but he might not be interpreting the different opacities

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem as you do. I fixed it to calculate and set the renderdepth for each mesh. For this you need the camera position and the center of your mesh.

You probably already created meshes for each object. If you save all these meshes into an array, it's easier to calculate and set the renderdepth on these objects.

Here's an example how I did it.

```
updateRenderDepthOnRooms(cameraPosition: THREE.Vector3): void {
    var rooms: Room[] = this.getAllRooms();

    rooms.forEach((room) => {
        var roomCenter = getCenter(room.mesh.geometry);  
        var renderDepth = 0 - roomCenter.distanceToSquared(cameraPosition);
        room.mesh.renderDepth = renderDepth;            
    });
}

function getCenter(geometry: THREE.Geometry): THREE.Vector3 {
    geometry.computeBoundingBox();

    var bb = geometry.boundingBox;
    var offset = new THREE.Vector3();

    offset.addVectors(bb.min, bb.max);
    offset.multiplyScalar(0.5);

    return offset;
}
```

So, to get the center of your object, you can ask the geometry from your mesh and use the getCenter(..) function from my example. Then you calculate the renderdepth with the ThreeJs function distanceToSquared(..) and then set this renderdepth to your mesh.

That's it. Hope this will help you.